# Can て be omitted from て-form?

Tags: grammar, て-form

This is the expression in question: "お越しください".
I believe it should be: "お越してください".
Can someone help me understand why there's no て in the original sentence? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! I've found "【お越し】おこし
coming, going" in the JMDict English. 
But now that I'm paying more attention, I see that there's also "【又お越し下さいませ】またおこしくださいませ please come again"... So I guess it's an expression?